# How can I link one table with two reference tables in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
   IEnumerable<Job> jobs

   jobs = from t in table.GetAll()
             select new Job
            {
                Key1 = t.Key1,
                Key2 = t.Key2,
                Title = t.Title,
                Status = t.Status,
                Type = t.Type
            };
```

The Status and Type fields are keys and the value of these keys is stored in the following:

```
refStatus = from t in ref.GetAll()
           select new Ref
           {
                Key1 = "Status"
                Key2 = t.Key2,    // key that links to Status in the Jobs
                Title = t.Title   // Text value of the key
           }

  refType = from t in ref.GetAll()
           select new Ref
           {
                Key1 = "Type"
                Key2 = t.Key2,    // key that links to Type in the Jobs
                Title = t.Title   // Text value of the key
           }
```

Is there a way in LINQ that I can link the refStatus and refType tables to the first table and then have my jobs report show the text value of the Status and the Type instead of the key only?

```
public abstract class Job
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Ref
{
    public string Key1 { get; set; }
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for `Ref` and `Job` Classes. Anyway you probably want to look at `LINQ Join` method, MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx).

Comment: I added the code for the two classes. I looked at the Join method but I am confused as to how to use that and even more confused because this time there are three tables involved. To use LINQ to add in those tables would refType and refStatus have to be converted to IList<X> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var results =
    from j in table.GetAll()
    join s in refTableStatuses.GetAll() on j.Status equals s.Key2
    join t in refTableTypes.GetAll() on j.Type equals t.Key2
    select new Job
    {
        Key1 = j.Key1,
        Key2 = j.Key2,
        Title = j.Title,
        Status = s.Title, // value from Ref (Status) s
        Type = t.Title    // value from Ref (Type) t
    };
```

You probably need to somehow distinguish between status and type (as they come from same table and are represented by same entity). Since you didn't explain how you differentiate between them, I updated my query variables to reflect that.

Comment: They come from the same table but the key1 is set to Key1 = "Status" or it is set to "Type".  That's the way I know if the record is a status or type description. I will try our your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: What do you think of the other answer that has dictionaries? I am wondering which to use. Also would like to hear from anyone else who could suggest a way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @TracyBarlow: they're essentially the same. Only difference is that other answer allows you to preserve status and type dictionaries for future use - unless you really need that, I don't see a reason to clutter your code with extra variables.